# Bitcoin Core continuously downloading Blocks, How to stop it from downloading?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-wallet-app

I just installed Bitcoin Core (Windows Version) and Install it in my local machine and it started downloading showing 0.3% already downloaded and keep going. I tried to Disable Network Activity icon and also cancel it from task manager but again when I open it showing 0.6% downloaded. What is the way out to stop Bitcoin core software from downloading blocks?

Comment: I think it might be relevant to understand what you're trying to achieve. If you want just a wallet, there are some that don't download the blockchain. If you want to have a wallet that has its own source of truth regarding the state of the blockchain, you need the blockchain. If you don't want Bitcoin Core to download and verify the blockchain, why are you running Bitcoin Core and not something else?

Comment: "why not Bitcoin Core", not "why Bitcoin Core"

Answer (score 3):

Run Bitcoin Core with the `-noconnect` command line option, or with `connect=0` in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

There should be many ways to stop Bitcoin Core from downloading blocks:

- pass "-proxy" without making sense. For instance "-proxy=127.0.0.1:65535" (unless you unfortunately have a proxy listening there...)
- handle your operating system routing tables to leave Bitcoin in isolation by creating a network to nowhere
- logically disable network completely using your operating system, for all programs and services
- physically disable network by turning off your routers and switches, cables, antennas etc